# Migrating XML files from local directory to Snowflake data stage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, talend, staging, data-integration

Trying to perform the job which transfers files from the local directory to the Snowflake data stage I've met a blocker.
My job is going to be a replication of put commands as below:

```
put file:///talend_data_shared/PDGANA/SITESEL/SrcFiles/CITELN/ORG_2*.xml @PDG_DEV.PDG_ANALYTICS_STAGE.STAGE/xml1.0/ORG/;

TRUNCATE TABLE IF EXISTS "PDG_DEV"."PDG_ANALYTICS_STAGE"."CITELN_XML_ORG";

COPY INTO "PDG_DEV"."PDG_ANALYTICS_STAGE"."CITELN_XML_ORG" 
FROM @PDG_DEV.PDG_ANALYTICS_STAGE.STAGE/&CD/xml1.0/ORG/
FILE_FORMAT = '"PDG_DEV"."PDG_ANALYTICS_STAGE"."XML"' 
ON_ERROR = 'ABORT_STATEMENT' 
PURGE = TRUE;
```

In job I read `*.xml` file by tFileInputXML comp. and I'm trying to write data using tDBOutputBulkExec comp. with the setup as below.
[image]

The problem is that tDBOutputBulkExec writes data on the Snowflake stage as gz extension, but the challenge is to save it with `*.xml.gz` extension as it happens via executing the command in the SnowSQL console. The `*.xml.gz` extension allows copying `*.xml` content from staged files to tables at the next step.
[image]

Do you have any suggestions for this case?

Comment: HI - just wondering, as you have Talend, why you are loading the data into a stage and not directly into a Snowflake table?

Comment: The Snowflake PUT command has an AUTO_COMPRESS option. It defaults to TRUE, and the only option is gzip, which will add a .gz extension. Snowflake will automatically decompress those files on read, so it's best to leave it enabled. If you really want to disable compression, you can set `AUTO_COMPRESS = FALSE` in your PUT statement.

Comment: Hi Guys,
I already found a resolution that works pretty well. Unfortunately Put and Copy operations needs to be implemented to componnents and different jobs otherwise some problems with command executing may occur.

1. “Put file” job
One way to keep .xml file extension after staging file was using tDBRow with put query.

2. “Copy into” job
I've used tDBBulkExec.

Thanks for your replies.